# need Jolt Spec to convent JSON array key name to updated name

Tags: json, jolt

Original JSON message:

```
[
  {
    "correlationId": "12345",
    "payloadFormat": "Money",
    "payload": {
      "stateName": "TX",
      "location": "south",
      "name": "Dallas",
      "pop": "2M"
    }
  },
  {
    "correlationId": "ed1e3",
    "payloadFormat": "Cash",
    "payload": {
      "stateName": "CA",
      "location": "west",
      "name": "LosAngeles",
      "pop": "4M"
    }
  }
]
```

Output should be in below format:

```
[
  {
    "correlationId": "12345",
    "payloadFormat": "Money",
    "payload": {
      "California": "TX",
      "MontGomery": "south",
      "City": "Dallas",
      "ID": "2M"
    }
  },
  {
    "correlationId": "ed1e3",
    "payloadFormat": "Cash",
    "payload": {
      "California": "CA",
      "MontGomery": "west",
      "City": "LosAngeles",
      "ID": "4M"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "correlationId": "[&1].correlationId",
        "payloadFormat": "[&1].payloadFormat",
        "payload": {
          "stateName": "[&2].payload.California",
          "location": "[&2].payload.MontGomery",
          "name": "[&2].payload.City",
          "pop": "[&2].payload.ID"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot, My issue gets resolved with this solution